# Admob Link To Firebase not Showing in App Settings

Tags: firebase, admob

I logged into `adMob` and created an app then created a `Banner Unit` and an `Interstitial Unit`.

From there I went to:

`Apps` -> `Select Your App` -> `App Settings` and when I went to look for the `Link to Firebase` link it's not there. It shows `User Metrics` instead.

[image]

**This is the what it should show:**

[image]

I created 3 different apps and it's not appearing for any of them nor any of their ad units.

**Where is the Link to Firebase now located because it isn’t in any of the left sidebar icons or anywhere on that site whatsoever?**

Comment: If you have a question about working with Firebase services in a web console, please contact Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson Hi Doug, I saw you on a couple of firebase videos so I'm sure you know what you're talking about. Would this be more of a firebase problem or an admob problem?

Comment: I've never used admob before, so I can't help.

Comment: ok thanks, I'll email firebase support and see what they say. Have a nice day.

Comment: Any updates on this ?

Comment: I emailed FBSupport and they said it’s an AdMob issue. I posted it to their forums and an admin answered and said that he saw/confirmed it wasn’t showing on my end and he would bring it to the teams attention. He did suggest I post it to a different AdMob forum which I did and the only thing someone asked was was I logged in to both with the same email -I was. Other then that nothing. Later on I’ll post updates. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Jonathan I added a detailed incomplete answer with everyone I've contacted about this so far. Please read it. Whenever I get the issue resolved I'll update the complete answer and let you know.

Comment: Hello, I have reverse issue. I could see "Link to Firebase" in my account. But I doesn't see "User Metrics" settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer to this question is **at this moment  the link to firebase no longer exists but will be added back in the near future**. Here is the the response from Firebase Support (it's also at the bottom of the convo)

**There were recent changes in AdMob side where new accounts will be onboarded to User Metrics automatically. At the moment, it wouldn't be possible for new AdMob accounts to link Firebase, but will be likely available again after a few months. Also, AdMob is now working on updating their documentation to explain these changes.**

[image]

The Firebase Link is optional, **it isn't necessary to link to it to serve ads**. Read [here](http://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase) and it states: *Firebase is recommended, but **optional**. The best way to use AdMob is with Firebase, but for those publishers who aren't ready to make the switch just yet, the Google Mobile Ads SDK can be used as a **standalone** SDK.*

***IMPORTANT: Be sure to follow the directions from [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start) and [this page](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start) on what to add in your info.plist***

Here is a flow of the convo between Firebase Support, AdMob SDK, and AdMob Help Center since I posted this question.

In the comments underneath the original question @DougStevenson suggested that I contact [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact?visit_id=637038278975860968-4204235071&rd=1) which I did:

> Subject: Admob Link To Firebase not Showing in App Settings (look in
>   attachment)
>
> FirebaseCore (6.2.2) Firebase/CoreOnly (6.8.0) FirebaseAnalytics
>   (6.1.1) Firebase/AdMob (6.8.0) Xcode 10.2.1 Swift 5
>
> I had an admob account under 1 email address with 3 apps tied to it.
>   All the apps were using test ads and never went live. I decided to
>   change my email address and signed up for another admob account with
>   the new address. Unbeknownst to me you're not allowed to have 2
>   accounts and there isn't anywhere on any of the pages that said that.
>   After I signed up for the new account and linked some new apps I got
>   an email from the old account saying I cannot have 2 accounts and I
>   needed to delete one of them. I immediately deleted the old account.
>
> 1. The first problem is my 3 old apps from the old admob account are still linked to the old account and I cannot unlink them because the
>      account is deleted. There is no mention of them in my new account
>      because I never added them to the new account.
> 2. I'm assuming because of this in my new admob account there isn't a "link to firebase" link anywhere. I've been looking around for hours
>      and I have no way to link my new apps to my new account because the
>      option is not anywhere to be found (look in attachment).
>
> I went to the the old firebase and added my new email address as an
>   "Owner" under "Users and Permissions" and then did the same thing
>   with the new firebase account (linked the old email address as owner).
>   On neither account do I have access to unlink the old projects and I
>   still can't link my new projects to admob.
>
> There seems to be a firebase bug that got confused with the old admob
>   vs new admob
>
> Here is the account info from the old admob account. These are the
>   apps I want to unlink from admob:
>
> email address -firstAccountCompanyName@gmail.com
>   com.firstAccountCompanyName.appNameOne, -projectId: aaa
>   com.firstAccountCompanyName.appNameTwo, -projectId: bbb
>   com.firstAccountCompanyName.appNameThree, -projectId: ccc
>
> This is the new admob account that doesn't give me the option to link
>   my new apps to firebase admob:
>
> email address -secondAccountCompanyName@gmail.com
>   com.secondAccountCompanyName.appOne, -projectId: xxx
>   com.secondAccountCompanyName.appTwo -projectId: yyy
>   com.secondAccountCompanyName.appThree, -projectId: zzz
>
> Thanks

This was their response:

> Firebase Support
>
> Hi Lance,
>
> Apologies, but this seems to be an AdMob specific issue which is
>   beyond our scope  of support. Since linking of AdMob and Firebase is
>   done in AdMob console, I would encourage you to use our help
>   resources. You can find answers to most AdMob questions by visiting:
>
> [AdMob help center](https://support.google.com/admob#topic=7383088) 
>   [Inside AdMob blog](https://www.blog.google/products/admob/) 
>   [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk)
>
> You may also check this page for common Firebase linking errors. If
>   you need more support, you can contact using one of the forms
>   available in the help center.
>
> Regards,

I then went to [Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-admob-ads-sdk) and posted the same thing I sent to firebase to the the google [groups message board](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/2GvjpxbIzaU) and here is the convo. Pay attention to the second point he brought up (I highlighted it in bold):

> Hi Lance,
>
> 1. You may visit [this page](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/7652532?hl=en) to learn about AdMob's policy on multiple accounts. With that said, note that this forum is for us to assist you
>      in your technical implementation of the AdMob SDK. I would thus
>      recommend posting this particular concern over at the [AdMob Help
>      Center](https://support.google.com/admob/community?hl=en) instead for further assistance, as the product specialists
>      there will be able to provide better insights on this.
> 2. **I can confirm that I could not see any mention of Firebase linking during my investigation as well.** I will discuss this with the rest of
>      the team, and get back to you on this as soon as possible.
>
> Regards

My reponse to the team member:

> Thank you for getting back to me, I really appreciate it. I sent a
>   message to the Firebase team and their response was
>
> "Apologies, but this seems to be an AdMob specific issue which is
>   beyond our scope  of support. Since linking of AdMob and Firebase is
>   done in AdMob console, I would encourage you to use our help
>   resources. You can find answers to most AdMob questions by visiting ..."
>
> I'm sort of in limbo as I've been googling around since yesterday and
>   it seems to be a weird situation. Anyway again I appreciate the help
>   and hopefully there is a resolution.
>
> Cheers!

His response:

> Hi Lance,
>
> Thank you for your patience on this matter.
>
> I've discussed your concern with the rest of the team, and we've come
>   to the recommendation that you post this concern over at the [AdMob
>   Help Center](https://support.google.com/admob/community?hl=en) as well, since the product specialists there will be able
>   to assist you better on this non-technical concern. Don't forget to
>   include the same screenshots as you've posted here to help in
>   expediting assistance.
>
> Regards,

I posted the [same question](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/13983460?hl=en) to the [AdMob Help Center](https://support.google.com/admob/community?hl=en) and the response I got was from this person but I'm unsure if this an AdMob specialist or a regular person:

> Jess Day
>
> hi there,  Confirm that you're using the same email address for both
>   AdMob and Firebase. Confirm that the project you're linking to hasn't
>   been deleted.

My response:

> @JessDay, hello yes the email address for both are the same. The new
>   email address is in the same browser for login on both platforms.
>
> Both projects are still active but neither are live, they are both
>   local to my cpu. I haven't deleted the old project because I still use
>   it for testing.

That's pretty much where things are at the moment.

I did find [another thread](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/12976824) where someone else had the same problem so at least I know it's not something that I did wrong and isn't unique to me.

**Update**

Its been a week and nothing from anyone about this very frustrating ridiculous problem. I emailed the original person i spoke to at adMob and even though he admits there is a problem he says there is nothing he can do to help. He can't even email anyone over there. Horrible Horrible Horrible.

My follow up email:

> Hello Ziv,
>
> I still haven't heard from anyone about this odd issue. Is there
>   anybody on your team who possibly knows someone over there who can
>   find out what the issue is? If you look at this link
>   https://support.google.com/admob/thread/12976824 you'll see that
>   others are having the same issue and it seems more and more people are
>   running into this problem. Even the adviser on the page Britonatona is
>   perplexed about this issue. She basically passed the buck.
>
> I've tried everything imaginable and the link does not exist. Maybe
>   you can make a foo account and see for your self. The docs on this
>   page https://support.google.com/admob/answer/9263723, under Enable
>   User Metrics gives directions on how to enable User Metrics. The
>   problem is the docs on this page
>   https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6383165?hl=en literally give
>   the same exact instructions on how to link to firebase following the
>   same exact instructions from the first page. One of them of them is
>   wrong. Someone on one team must've made a decision without consulting
>   someone on another team because both sets of instructions are current
>   but yet the link to firebase is no longer there. Also, on the main
>   page where you can view all of your apps, there used to be a link to
>   firebase on the right hand side of the page for each, it's no longer
>   there, user metrics is now there (attachment).
>
> I've linked Analytics and Google Ads via Firebase Database
>   (attachment) but nothing helps. I'm actually launching an app this
>   week and I'm stuck because I can't link the project to my account and
>   there isn't anyone I can contact for assistance.
>
> Please from one developer to another developer see what you can find
>   out.
>
> Thanks

[image]

His response:

> Hi Lance,
>
> Thank you for sharing the results of your extensive investigations on
>   your side.
>
> I did check the presence of any Firebase options in my own AdMob test
>   account the first time you've shared this concern with us, and can
>   confirm the lack of it on my end as well.
>
> At this point, I must apologize for the back-and-forth discussion that
>   we've been having; I would also, however, like to reiterate that this
>   forum is for us to assist you on the technical implementation of the
>   AdMob SDK. For non-technical matters, I would still recommend
>   contacting the AdMob Help Center for further assistance.
>   Regards, Ziv Yves Sanchez Mobile Ads SDK Team

My response with no response back:

> Hi Ziv, Yes I remember you said you couldn't see it on your side. The
>   thing is I'm not sure what type of problem this is. Is it a technical
>   problem or a design change without updating the docs. That's where the
>   problem lies, the docs say one thing but shows another.
>
> I posted the issue to the forum but other people also posted the same
>   issue and no one has gotten any results.
>
> I have no idea what to do at this point. The only thing I can do is
>   keep reposting the same issue.

This is crazy. How does someone in one part of a company acknowledge a problem on the company's end and instead of helping you they just say in but so many words "ehhh just go post that problem over there".

**Update 9/27/19**

It's been about 2 weeks now and still nothing. [Someone else had the same problem](https://support.google.com/admob/thread/12976824?hl=en) and I added the below comment to their thread and an admin name *Rodrigo F* finally took notice and thankfully took action:

Here's a screen shot of the convo:

[image]

**Update 10/08/19:**

> Rodrigo F
>
> Here is the answer I received from the team:
>
> In this case the pub can reach out to the Firebase support -
>   https://firebase.google.com/support?category=troubleshooting&hl=en
>   This may also happen due to the complexity of Firebase. Firebase can
>   only be linked with the first email id that was used to create it. For
>   example if the company has 2 employees and Firebase was created using
>   the id of Emp1 then Emp2 cannot use his email id or company email id
>   to relink Firebase (in the absence of Emp1).

My Response:

> @RodrigoF Thanks for getting back to us.
>
> A few things:
>
> 1. The link they gave us sends us to Firebase but the very first thing I did before I posted here was contact Firebase directly (at that
>      exact link) about this issue and their response was to post over here:
>
> "Firebase Support -Subject: Case 00010594
>
> Hi Lance, Apologies, but
>   this seems to be an AdMob specific issue which is beyond our scope of
>   support. Since linking of AdMob and Firebase is done in AdMob console,
>   I would encourage you to use our help resources. You can find answers
>   to most AdMob questions by visiting: AdMob help center Inside AdMob
>   blog Google Mobile Ads SDK Developers You may also check this page for
>   common Firebase linking errors. If you need more support, you can
>   contact using one of the forms available in the help center. Regards"
>
> 2. I followed their directions and posted the problem here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/ios/2GvjpxbIzaU.
>      I spoke with Ziv Yves Sanchez and when he tried on his end on his
>      machine he also confirmed that the link was missing:
>
> "I can confirm that I could not see any mention of Firebase linking
>   during my investigation as well." "I did check the presence of any
>   Firebase options in my own AdMob test account the first time you've
>   shared this concern with us, and can confirm the lack of it on my end
>   as well."
>
> Ziv said to post the problem over here in the AdMob Help Center:
>
> "Hi Lance, Thank you for your patience on this matter. I've discussed
>   your concern with the rest of the team, and we've come to the
>   recommendation that you post this concern over at the AdMob Help
>   Center as well, since the product specialists there will be able to
>   assist you better on this non-technical concern. Don't forget to
>   include the same screenshots as you've posted here to help in
>   expediting assistance."
>
> 3. I posted the question https://support.google.com/admob/thread/13983460?hl=en and got no
>      response
> 4. I had my daughter create an account at AdMob from her gmail on her phone (I never accessed AdMob nor FB from her device before) and she
>      had nothing in Firebase nor did she ever have an AdMob account before.
>      After she created an app for AdMob the Firebase link was not anywhere
>      to be found. How can they explain that? There were no other employees
>      nor any other accounts nor anyone else.
> 5. In my situation  I created an AdMob account under one email address, linked it to one Firebase account, then created another email
>      address and linked to an entirely different Firebase Account. I got an
>      email that said I needed to delete one of them because i was only
>      allowed to have 1 account. I followed the email and deleted it. The
>      thing is after following the directions I was given the Firebase link
>      still didn't show.
> 6. The response the Firebase teammate gave seems to explain one problem but it doesn't give a solution. I doubt all the people in this
>      thread created 2 accounts like me but more importantly the account my
>      daughter made was completely brand new/fresh and the link didn't
>      appear for her either. Ziv Yves Sanchez (an AdMob team member) also
>      acknowledged the issue. This seems to be beyond 2 people with email
>      addresses for 1 firebase account.
> 7. So now that the Firebase team member sent that response what should we do next? Can you please find out a solution because as i said
>      earlier I already posted to them and they said to post it over here.
> 8. Have you tried to make a brand new test account just to see if the link appears for you?
>
> The problem is Firebase Support said to post to Google Mobile Ads SDK
>   Developers who said to post to the AdMob Help Center who said to post
>   to Firebase Support.
>
> Regards,

**Update 10/09/19**

As I stated in my earlier messages when I first ran into this problem I contacted Firebase Support and they told me to contact the AdMob SDK team who told me to contact the AdMob Help team who told us (everyone in the thread) to contact Firebase Support.

I reached back out to Firebase Support via the previous email communication we had about this issue and I also created a new ticket. In both messages to them I explained the way I was told to go back right to them and asked the rep to create a new AdMob account, look at the docs on how to add the Firebase Link, and he would see that the link has been removed. Here is his response below:

> Hi Lance,
>
> I'm sorry that you had to go all through these circular responses. I
>   noticed that you opened a new ticket reporting the similar issue. I'll
>   be closing the new ticket (#0015676) to avoid duplicate efforts and
>   please refer to this ticket for my responses moving forward.
>
> I tried creating a new account in AdMob and I can confirm that the
>   option to link Firebase doesn't exists in AdMob console. It seems like
>   there are changes in the front end of AdMob console for newly created
>   accounts. Since the changes are from AdMob console, I can't guarantee
>   that I could provide solutions but I'll do my best anyway. I'm
>   currently discussing your issue with our gurus. I'll get back to you
>   within a week or as soon as I have information to share.
>
> Thanks, Richard

**Update 10/10/19**

I just got this message back from Richard a Firebase Support. The firebase link is **no longer available**. They have to update their docs to reflect that.

> Thanks for your insights. It looks like it is currently an intended
>   behavior. There were recent changes in AdMob side where new accounts
>   will be onboarded to User Metrics automatically. At the moment, it
>   wouldn't be possible for new AdMob accounts to link Firebase, but will
>   be likely available again after a few months. Also, AdMob is now
>   working on updating their documentation to explain these changes.

I asked will I be able to still serve ads with the App ID in the info.plist and the App Unit ID in the view controller and I'm waiting for his response. I'll update once I get it.

**Last Update 10/14/19:**

Here is a message from Kate at AdMob Help. **The link to Firebase is not necessary to serve ads.**

[image]

[Here is the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase) from the image

Specifically:

[image]

Comment: I am facing this same issue. No "Link to Firebase." option there. Did you get any solution for it? Thanks.

Comment: @Tulon no solution yet. The most recent response I got from FBSupport was early this morning, it’s the last message at the bottom. They said they’d get back to me by next week. Once I get an answer from them I’ll add it to the answer. I’ll message you too.

Comment: What a bummer! That's a long time. I hope they will give a proper solution to you. Waiting...Thanks

Comment: I have same issue

Comment: I have reverse issue. I could see "Link to Firebase" in my account. But I doesn't see "User Metrics" setting.

Comment: @higsBozone when was the account created?

Comment: @LanceSamaria account was created 7 years ago in 2012

Comment: @higsBozone that’s why, it’s an old account. It’s only happening with brand new accounts as of July/Aug 2019 and on

Comment: @Tulon I just got an email from Firebase Support. I posted it as the last communication from them in my answer. The firebase no longer exists and they're updating their docs to reflect it.

Comment: @LanceSamaria Thanks a lot for your comment mate. Do you mean they are planning to integrate some other option rather than Firebase?

Comment: @Tulon I emailed him back and asked what should do I do in the meantime and he hasn't responded. I'm not sure what does that mean for new AdMob users who want to integrate it. Once he emails me back, I'll post the update and I'll message you to keep you abreast.

Comment: @LanceSamaria Appreciate your effort. Eagerly waiting for the reply...

Comment: @Tulon I got the last message from them. Firebase is optional, it isn't necessary to link to it to serve ads. Read here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/admob-firebase and specifically: **Firebase is recommended, but optional. The best way to use AdMob is with Firebase, but for those publishers who aren't ready to make the switch just yet, the Google Mobile Ads SDK can be used as a standalone SDK.**

Comment: @LanceSamaria Thanks for the update mate. I will go through the link. :)

Comment: @Tulon They added something new, make sure you add this to the info.plist too: https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/ios/quick-start

Comment: Sure I will. Thanks :)